# Comparison of two netCDF files

Tags: r, format, compare, netcdf

I am working on netCDF files and at each step I want to verify that the value of my temperature variable is the same. At each modification I save a new file and with R I am running this:

```
for (i in 1: (dim(time1)*dim(long1)*dim(lat1))) {if(var1[i] != var2[i]) {stop(paste("Not the same values",i))}}
```

Var1 is the temperature of my first file and var2 is the temperature of my second file (the modified one)

I have a message "Not the same values" when I compare a file with temperature as short to a file with temperature as float whereas it is the same value (I can see it when I paste it).

Is it normal and how can I verify if there is a problem of values on my modified file?

Comment: Probably an R-FAQ 7.31 problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment, I change to

```
for (i in 1: (dim(time1)*dim(long1)*dim(lat1))) {if(all.equal(var1[i], var2[i]) == FALSE) {stop(paste("Pas les mêmes valeurs",i))}}
```

and it works well