# Is there a way to compare the structure/architecture of .nc files in R?

Tags: r, netcdf

I have a sample .nc file that contains a number of variables (5 to be precise) and is being read into a program. I want to create a new .nc file containing different data (and different dimensions) that will also be read into that program.

I have created a .nc file that looks the same as my sample file (I have included all of the necessary attributes for each of the variables that were included in the original file).
However, my file is still not being ingested.

My question is: is there a way to test for differences in the layout/structure of .nc files?
I have examined each of the variables/attributes within Rstudio and I have also opened them in panoply and they look the same. There are obviously differences (besides the actual data that they contain) since the file is not being read.

I see that there are options to compare the actual data within .nc files online ([Comparison of two netCDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369899/comparison-of-two-netcdf-files)), but that is not what I want. I want to compare the variable/attributes names/states/descriptions/dimensions to see where my file differs. Is that possible?

The ideal situation here would be to create a .nc template from the variables that exist within the original file and then fill in my data. I could do this by defining the dimensions (`ncdim_def`), creating the file(`nc_create`), getting my data (`ncvar_get`) and putting it in the file (`ncvar_put`), but that is what I have done so far, and it is too reliant on me not making an error (which I obviously have as they are not the same).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on unix this is more easily achieved using CDO. See the Information section of the reference card: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/cdo_refcard.pdf.

For example, if you wanted to check that the descriptions are the same in files just do:

```
cdo griddes example1.nc

cdo griddes example2.nc
```

You can easily use `system` in R, to wrap around this.

Answer (score 0):

Th [`ncompare`](https://github.com/nasa/ncompare) tool does exactly the kind of structural (and metadata) comparison that you are asking for. It is a Python package that can be executed from a command line — so it could also be called from R using the `system` command.  *Note* that I am a developer for it.

Here's a description and a screenshot of it on NASA's Earthdata Forum: https://forum.earthdata.nasa.gov/viewtopic.php?t=4687.